# Why jest expects an anonymous function to catch an error?

Tags: testing, jestjs, tdd

I have not comprehended what's the reason behind the fact that expects a curried function when I want to test the output of the error message. If it was going to be a `return` value a direct call to the function leads to the value to be tested correctly in `.toBe`

```
function calculateMedian({numbers}) {
if (Array.isArray(numbers) && numbers.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Cannot calcuate median without any numbers');
    }
}
```

However, if i were to test the following snipped without the anonymous function the test will simply fail. What is the reason behind it?

**Passing Test**

```
    it('should throw an error when given an empty array', () => {
        expect(() =>
            calculateMedian({
                numbers: [],
            }),
        ).toThrow('Cannot calcuate median without any numbers');
    });
```

**Failing Test**

```
    it('should throw an error when given an empty array', () => {
        expect(calculateMedian({numbers: []})
        ).toThrow('Cannot calcuate median without any numbers');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`expect` and `toThrow` are just function calls. So, for the assertion on exception to work, the thing you pass as `expect` argument needs to allow for execution controlled by the testing framework.

The flow is similar to:

1. `expect()` saves the lambda as variable
2. `toThrow()` executes the saved variable in a `try/catch` block and tests the caught exception.

The way you would do it without the `toThrow` method would be similar to:

```js
try {
  calculateMedian({numbers: []};
  fail();
} catch (err) {
  expect(err.message).toBe('Cannot calcuate median without any numbers')
}
```

If, instead of passing a lambda/function you simply invoke the function, the error will be thrown before program control gets to the `toThrow` method. The test will fail because of the thrown error.